# Append to file succeeding but calling error from another def

Tags: python

When I specify the -a switch to add to config file for some reason this calls the read_config file also.  For example I use ./script.py -a newfile.txt and the file is added correctly but then returns "Config File not found".

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Copy multiple Files from a specified data file')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--configfile', default="config.dat", help='file to read the config from')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--location', default="/home/admin/Documents/backup/",help='Choose location to store files')
parser.add_argument('-a', '--add', help='add new line to config data')

def read_config(data):
    try:
        dest = '/home/admin/Documents/backup/'
        # Read in date from config.dat
        data = open(data)
        # Interate through list of files '\n'
        filelist = data.read().split('\n')
        # Copy through interated list and strip white spaces and empty lines
        for file in filelist:
            if file:
                shutil.copy(file.strip(), dest)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        logger.error("Config file not found")
        print ("Config File not found")
```

Not quite sure why this section below is working but read_config is called and finding the except error. Where am I going wrong?

```
def addtofile(add):
    f = open('config.dat', "a")
    f.write(add + '\n')
    f.close()

args = vars(parser.parse_args())
read = read_config(args['configfile'])
add = addtofile(args['add'])
```

Comment: You report that `read_config()` gets called when you don't expect it to be. But you don't show us the code where `addtofile()` gets called in response to `--add` and `read_config()` gets called in response to `--configfile`, and that is probably where the bug is.

Comment: ahh I missed that entry... Apologies... I have edited this and added this in.. 
Thanks for the help

Comment: What exactly is happening that you don't expect? `read_config()` is running because you tell it to, then `addtofile()` is running because you tell it to do that, too.

Comment: Maybe I got this confused.. I only want addtofile() to be called if switch -a is called using script.py -a, and not take in to account these

Comment: Then you'll need to put `if` statements around the function calls to check if the appropriate arg was set. As written, though, `configfile` will always be set, since you gave it a default value.

Comment: Makes sense now... bad coding.. Ill set if arg is called then do.... , etc
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c', action='store_true')

a = parser.parse_args()
if a.c:
    {
        print("get custom config")
    }
else:
    {
        print("using default config file")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution will be:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-c', action='store_true')

a = parser.parse_args()
if a.c:
{
    print("get custom config")
}
else:
{
    print("using default config file")
}
```